# Part of string matches any element of a list using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I want to find out if some part of a string is contained in a list of strings I allow, using regex.
For example, I would like to check if

```
"12_SUMMER_3456"
```

matches:

```
"\d*_(SUMMER|FALL|WINTER|SPRING)_\d*"
```

The thing is, I want to replace "**(SUMMER|FALL|WINTER|SPRING)**" with a list:

```
lst = ["SUMMER", "FALL", "WINTER", "SPRING"]
```

and then, use **lst** instead of explicitly give it's elements inside the regex.
Is there something like that in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join and interpolate the list.

```py
regex = r"\d*_(" + '|'.join(lst) + r")_\d*"
```

As an aside, that's equivalent to

```py
regex = r"_(" + '|'.join(lst) + r")_"
```

If something may or may not be there at the boundary of the match, you can simplify by taking it out; the regex will still match whether or not it's there. (If you are capturing or anchoring the match, then of course these are necessary for other reasons.)

The third-party [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library lets you say

```py
regex = r"\d*_L<lst>_\d*"
```

where again of course the `\d*` are redundant.
You need to `pip install regex` and then obvisously `import regex` instead of `import re`.